# What comic did Namor and Captain America fight in WWII in?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, avengers-vs-x-men

In the New Avengers #29, we see a panel of Namor, the Human Torch, Captain America and Wolverine (?) fighting in WWII against the Red Skull.

Is this collection of the four of them a reference to an existing comic?  If so, which one?

[image]

Comment: That's Bucky Captain America's sidekick not Wolverine and that's probably The Torch who was an android character around at that time.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [The Invaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_%28comics%29) from 1969

It was referenced during the Ed Brubaker run on Captain America as well.

It's also worth pointing out that that's the original Human Torch (Jim Hammond) not Johnny Storm.